# Selenium Chrome driver failed to start on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, google-chrome, selenium

I am getting the below error.Last two days are struggling and unable to figure out the issue.

```
unknown error: chrome failed to start
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),
platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any
stacktrace information)
```

My Environment details below

- Operating System : Windows 10
- Chrome Driver: 2.40
- Selenium: 3.12.0
- Java: 1.8.172

My Code is below

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");                
// Check Operating System
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
// Set OS Related Information
String wChromeDriverPath = "C:\\MyCloud\\external\\chromedriver.exe";
String wChromePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
String lChromeDriverPath = "/usr/bin/chromedriver";
String lChromePath = "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable";
// Set Windows as Default
String chromeDriverPath = wChromeDriverPath;
String chromePath = wChromePath;
// Set OS Specific Chrome Driver & Chrome   
if(osName.toLowerCase().indexOf("linux") >= 0){
    chromeDriverPath = lChromeDriverPath;
    chromePath = lChromePath;
}
//Set Chrome Driver 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);        
webdriver = null
if(osName.toLowerCase().indexOf("linux") >= 0){
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary(chromePath);
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox");        
    webdriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
else{
    //No Chrome Options. Need to See the Chrome Window for testing
    webdriver = new ChromeDriver();  
}
webdriver.get("about:blank");
```

Comment: Did you find a solution this issue? I'm facing the same, would be nice if you could share. (: